# jqueryui slider widget enhancer jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips implementation Issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I've found especially useful enhancer for jquery ui slider widget: [jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips](http://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/), that fit my needs almost exactly, except one thing:

I'm trying to implement $awesome2 example from demopage mentioned above, but i need larger range: `{min:-100,max:100}`

and [here is](http://jsfiddle.net/3qva9yfo/) what i have in result.

The question is how to change labels appearance frequency along with range incrementation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you question seems a little vague, but I will assume you want something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/3qva9yfo/1/

All the customisation from the way the sliders look should be done with CSS, so basically just change the CSS from:

```
#awesome2 .ui-slider-pip:nth-of-type(5n+1) > .ui-slider-line {
    height: 6px;
    background: #777;
}

#awesome2 .ui-slider-pip:nth-of-type(5n+1) > .ui-slider-label {
    display: block;
    top: 8px;
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

#awesome2 .ui-slider-pip:nth-of-type(10n+1) > .ui-slider-line {
    height: 10px;
    background: #222;
}

#awesome2 .ui-slider-pip:nth-of-type(10n+1) > .ui-slider-label {
    display: block;
    top: 12px;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

to:

```
#awesome2 .ui-slider-pip:nth-of-type(1n+1) > .ui-slider-line {
    height: 6px;
    background: #777;
}

#awesome2 .ui-slider-pip:nth-of-type(1n+1) > .ui-slider-label {
    display: block;
    top: 8px;
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

#awesome2 .ui-slider-pip:nth-of-type(5n+1) > .ui-slider-line {
    height: 10px;
    background: #222;
}

#awesome2 .ui-slider-pip:nth-of-type(5n+1) > .ui-slider-label {
    display: block;
    top: 12px;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Remember in future we need to know what you want, to help you get it :)

Si.

Comment: sorry for the vague question, but the answer - just on target

Comment: It's up to you, but it will be helpful for the rest of the community if you could update your question to be a little clearer :) -- lots of people "google" for the answers to their questions and SEO is important.